# How to get height of element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `DOM` element,with `id={{child.id}}container`

```
 <div id={{child.id}}container layout="column" flex layout-align="start center" class='container' dragula='"first-bag"' ng-init="vm.getAssociatedWorkItems(child.id); vm.getElementHeight(child.id+'container');">
    <div layout="column" class="md-whiteframe-5dp capitalize itemsInList" ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:search" id={{item.id}}child>
        <div class="workItemName">{{vm.getWorkItemName(item.metadata)}}</div>
        <div class="workItemDescription">{{vm.getWorkItemDescription(item.metadata)}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get height of this element, and according to height deside to list items in `ng-repeat` or not. How to get `DOMs` height in `angularjs`?

Comment: Why should it impact the use of ng-repeat or not ?

Comment: I height is small I don't want to show items in ng-repeat.

Comment: you can use 'dir-paginate' an angular js pagination plugin.. based on your count it will display fixed number of records. after that pagination will come...

Comment: But why ? Is there a significant reason to not use ng-repeat ?

Comment: dir paginate is extended form of ng-repeat with pagination..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use angular built-int jqlite with angular.element():

```
angular.element(".myDiv")[0].offsetHeight;
```

Beware: don't pollute your controller with DOM manipulation. It's a bad practise and you should do this kind of operations in **directives**.

### Edit 1

OP used this mid way after my suggestion:

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#id')); 
var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
```

Comment: when I use :  var x = angular.element('#'+id+'container');
           console.log(x);    I receive: j…y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#165container"}. Cannot height height from there

Comment: Try with the standard javascript way: var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.ass')); and then element[0].offsetHeight

Comment: @Luxor001 will this give us the height of div in `ng-repeat` also ? If the limit is set to 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

in **angularjs** it is advised to manipulate the DOM elements ,into directives.Into directives we also use jquery.
So, you add the '**my-directive**' name into the element, like so:

```
<div my-directive id={{child.id}}container layout="column" flex layout-align="start center" class='container' dragula='"first-bag"' ng-init="vm.getAssociatedWorkItems(child.id); vm.getElementHeight(child.id+'container');">
    <div layout="column" class="md-whiteframe-5dp capitalize itemsInList" ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:search" id={{item.id}}child>
        <div class="workItemName">{{vm.getWorkItemName(item.metadata)}}</div>
        <div class="workItemDescription">{{vm.getWorkItemDescription(item.metadata)}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Into js, you create the directive that gets the height:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var elementHeight = element.height();
            console.log(elementHeight);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This would only work if JQuery is available BEFORE angular is loaded. Otherwise, only JQLite is available, which does not have this function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular's $element service, which is a jqLite wrapper for your component/directive.
Try something similar in your controller:

```
controller: function($element) {
angular.foreach(
    $element.find('.md-whiteframe-5dp, .capitalize, .itemsInList')
        .children(), function(element){
            var el = angular.element(element);
            if(el.hasClass('workItemName')){
                // do something with workItemName DOM element
            }
            if(el.hasClass('workItemDescription')){
                // do something with workItemDescription DOM element
            }
        });
```